# MySQLi close in destructor fires immediately

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli

I've recently been redesigning an archaic PHP application, which had most of it's code in 1000+ line long PHP files for each page. I first started by refactoring much of the code into classes. I recently have been working on database connections, and began writing a class for it. I decided to throw `$mysqli->close()` into the destructor (I'm using the OO approach).

Unfortunately I've almost immediately ran in to problems with it. Instead of the MySQLi connection closing when the page finishes rendering (or when there are no more references to the DB object), it just immediately closes. I've tested this through writing a simple test:

```
$db = new DBConnect(); //My abstraction class
$db->getSQL()->query("SELECT 1"); //Query fails. Error message states connection closed.
```

My destructor looks like this:

```
public function __destruct() {
    $this->mysqli->close();
}
```

My constructor looks like this:

```
public function __construct() {
     $this->mysqli=new mysqli(\MainConfig::$database['host'], \MainConfig::$database['user'], \MainConfig::$database['pass'], \MainConfig::$database['db']);
     if($this->mysqli->connect_error) {
          die('Connect error (' . $this->mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $this->mysqli->connect_error); //This is not ever fired.
     }
}
```

I know it's not some other bit of code closing the connection, since if I comment out the `$this->mysqli->close()` line, then the code works as expected. It seems to me that the destructor fires **immediately** which is not the desired behavior. Am I misunderstanding how they are intended to work?

Comment: Looks like there is a bit of code missing that is causing that. PHP garbage collector won't destruct an object unless there is no reference to it anymore.

Comment: Does each `DBConnect` instance have its own mysqli connection object, or do you cache them and share them across different objects?

Comment: @b.enoit.be all source files in the project replicate this behavior, including the test code there. I cannot post a 1000 line long source file!

Comment: Post the constructor as well.

Comment: @Barmar Each DBConnect instance has it's own internal MySQLi instance.

Comment: Add an `echo` statement to the destructor to see when it's being called.

Comment: IMHO, there's generally little point to closing mysqli connections explicitly. If $db is a global variable, it won't go away until the script ends, and the connection will be closed automatically.

Comment: @Barmar, constructor edited in, and I read on the PHP doc site somewhere (I don't have a link I'm sorry) that not explicitly closing connections can result in aborted MySQL connections popping up, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @duper51 if you cannot narrow it, then, there is not much we can do for you. Please note that `$this->mysqli` is actually your connection. If you happen to null it or to unset it or to destroy is somehow, you will get the same error, although your destructor won't be called.

Comment: `$this->mysqli` is private, and can only be accessed through another function called `getSQL()`. I did a quick find through my project and the only reference to `mysqli->close` is in the destructor of this class.

Comment: @duper51 That's not my experience. I've been using mysql, mysqli, and PDO for years and I never explicitly close them (PDO doesn't even have a close operation). The documentation says *Open non-persistent MySQL connections and result sets are automatically destroyed when a PHP script finishes its execution.*

Comment: Instead of just an echo, use [debug_print_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php) in the destructor. Then you'll see where it's being called from.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? GC behavior may have changed subtly between versions.

Comment: @duskwuff PHP 5.6.30

Answer (score 3):

I was able to reproduce the behavior you described with the code:

```
<?php

class DestructorTest {
    public function getter() {
        print "DestructorTest::getter() called\n";
        return new CallableTest();
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        print "DestructorTest destructor called\n";
    }
}

class CallableTest {
    public function method() {
        print "CallableTest::method() called\n";
    }
}

(new DestructorTest())->getter()->method();
```

which prints:

```
DestructorTest::getter() called
DestructorTest destructor called
CallableTest::method() called
```

The long and the short of it is: A destructor may be called as soon as there are no references to an object. This can even happen in the middle of a line -- in this case, for instance, after `DestructorTest:getter()` is called, the DestructorTest object is no longer reachable, so it is destroyed.

My advice:

- You don't need to close MySQLi handles. They already have an internal destructor which will close them when they are garbage-collected.
- In fact: avoid writing destructor methods in general. (This applies to many programming languages, not just PHP.) They are frequently not called when you expect them to be, and have a tendency to cause strange, hard-to-debug behavior.
- If you're going to ignore this and write a destructor anyways, then you need to make sure that you don't inadvertently destroy something which you've "leaked" a reference to outside your class. In the case of your code, you've allowed code outside the class to get a reference to your MySQLi handle, but you're destroying that handle as soon as your object goes away -- even if the handle is still being used outside.

Comment: But he's assigning the object to a variable, not calling a method on a temporary result. That should keep the pointer around and prevent the destructor from being called.

Comment: I agree, though I'm starting to get the idea that destructors are almost unnecessary in this case. I currently have it disabled to have the code work at all, I may just leave it like that. It doesn't make sense to me why if I don't close the MySQLi connection, the code still works. Doesn't that imply that the destructor was called, but the object still exists?

Comment: @Barmar That's true. I can't explain the behavior based on the code included in the question; the code I've provided is the closest I could come to reproducing the issue.

Comment: It's also worth using connection pooling to recycle existing connections.